# Using NotBlank annotation is not working in Kotlin code

Tags: kotlin, bean-validation

I want to convert my java class to Kotlin data class But I find that @NotBlank is not  working in kotlin.
 is there any alternative for this for kotlin.

```
@Data
public class myClass{

    @NotBlank(message = "url is missing")
    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;

    public myClass(@NotBlank(message = "url is missing") String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set a proper targer for validation annotation, like:

```
@Data
public class myClass{

    @field:NotBlank(message = "url is missing")
    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;

    public myClass(@field:NotBlank(message = "url is missing") String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

}
```

There are few options:

For a field
@field:NotBlank

For a getter
@get:NotBlank

For a constructor
@param:NotBlank

More info here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets

Comment: Strange I can get `@field:NotNull` to work but not `@field:NotBlank`